# Match string in text after last dot

Tags: javascript

I have the following strings:

```
var a = "vm.model.password";
var b = "vm.model.passwordCheck";
```

And I have the following:

```
var sa = "Password";
var sb = "PasswordCheck";
```

I need to check that sa is contained in a and sb in b.

So to compare I need to check the string in a or b after the dot.
And check if the sa is equal to that string but making the first letter of sa to lowercase first.

I was doing something like:

```
a.indexOf(sa.toLowerCase()) > -1;
```

But the problem is that sa would be a match of b to and sb would not be a match for b because it starts with P and not p.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Before I offer an answer, can you explain what you're doing and why? I suspect your approach isn't the best way to do what you're trying to accomplish but I can't say for sure without more information.

Comment: Basically, on an Angular application I have something like this on HTML <span class="error" data-validator="vm.model.password"></span>. vm.user.password is the property on the Angular model. But the API returns errors associated with properties with names like Password, e.g, without the vm.model. And in Angular CamelCase is used but the API returns always PasswordCheck starting with uppercase. So I need to map what the API returns to what Angular uses in the HTML

Comment: Then to be honest, why not just create a mapping? You're going to write all this logic, then what happens when you have a field called 'userName' and the API has 'UName' or something like that which doesn't fit the pattern? Just keep an associative array mapping one to the other.

Comment: That won't happen because it would break everything.

Comment: did you try the method I posted below? did that work ?

Comment: @Omarjmh just marked it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As far as getting the last word:**

what about using `str.lastIndexOf('.')` which is much faster than split():

```
var a = "vm.model.password";
var b = "vm.model.passwordCheck";

console.log(a.slice(a.lastIndexOf('.') + 1))
// a .toLowerCase at the end should do it
```

JSbin: https://jsbin.com/komowi/edit?js,console

Given how you are running into problems with uppercase/lowercase letters it might be time to look at a RegExp which has an 'i' flag on it which means it will match with case[MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
This isnt needed per say, but surely will help down the road

Comment: You have a bad ; after console.log. Otherwise, this way will be faster than doing a split.

Comment: Significantly? No. However, split requires that the entire string be iterated over then it has to construct an array. In your case, as soon as I hit the last . (starting from the end) I bail out. So if my string were 500 chars and the . was 3 from the end, your code only requires iterating over 3 chars, not 500 as split would.

Comment: thanks, I started thinking it out right after I asked, hence the delete.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, if the word you want to check is always at the end.

```
var aArray = a.split(".");
sa.toLowerCase() === aArray[aArray.length-1].toLowerCase();
```

Comment: a needs to be `toLowerCase` as well. When `sb` is made lowercase it becomes `passwordcheck` whereas b would be `passwordCheck` and would not match

Comment: I am not sure that it will be always vm.model.password. It could be vm.model.test.password so I need to get it after the last dot

Answer (score 1):

With pop() you get the last element of the array.

```
if( sa.toLowerCase() == a.split(".").pop() ){
 //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
var a = "vm.model.password";
var b = "vm.model.passwordCheck";

var sa = "Password";
var sb = "PasswordCheck";

var endA = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
var endB = b.substring(a.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

if (endA.includes(sa.toLowerCase())) {
    alert("A match");
}

if (endB.includes(sb.toLowerCase())) {
    alert("B match");
}
```

Obviously, you should check that it contains a '.' or that the lastIndexOf result is >= 0, etc, but I've avoided such validations for simplicity here.

Comment: `.contains()` was changed to `.includes()`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
a.toLowerCase().split('.').pop() === sa.toLowerCase()

b.toLowerCase().split('.').pop() === sb.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: I think this is the most inefficient solution offered thus far. You're requiring to create an array then modify the array. This should be done using only string manipulation.

Comment: I would like to be fast as I have a few strings as this on each API request. So pop is slow for this, correct?

Comment: @Miguel to be clear when I say "slow" we're talking milliseconds. That being said, it's not just the pop (which has to modify an array) it's split() which has to construct an array, `lastIndexOf` is going to be the fastest way to go.